# Deactivate WIFI MAC spoofing on Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W with DHCPCD?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w-2, dhcpcd

After the same update/upgrade I did to my 10 Raspberries (Pi Zero 2W), 4 out of them keep on using when connecting to my WiFi, a MAC Address which is not the hardware one (the one I see via `ifconfig`). All of those 4 MACs seem to follow the pattern `1A-D6-C7-78-E3-XX`. Hence, I cannot use properly IP reservation for them. How can I force a fixed MAC (the hardware one)? I am using dhcpcd and in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, I have:

```
# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
```

Also, I would like to avoid installing NetworkManager. My boards are:

```
description: ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
product: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0
network: logical_name=wlan0 broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=9.88.4 firmware=01-3b307371
```

I also have `force_mac_address=00:00:00:00:00:00` in `config.txt` but still no luck.

Comment: **This is not normal**, so it is hard to tell you how to undo something without with a mystery cause.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS does NOT change MAC. This has nothing to do with dhcpcd. Others who have experienced similar problems have found it is done by some software package they installed. I do not remember which but searching this site should show.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not normal.  However, a little bit of searching turned up [this thread on the Foundation's forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=241423) which sounds a lot like your problem; my cursory reading of it is that there is a `.dtb` file used which causes the kernel to create a new MAC address at boot.

There may also be something in `cmdline.txt`; if `grep /boot/cmdline.txt` shows anything, try removing that parameter.

There is the suggestion to add:

```
force_mac_address=00:00:00:00:00:00
```

to `/boot/config.txt`.  This is better explained here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2990

> This patch prefers a MAC address in the Device Tree to that in the EEPROM. Fortunately, an all-zeroes MAC address is ignored by Linux; try adding "force_mac_address=00:00:00:00:00:00" to config.txt.